# JS FadeIn not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to get a fading background image script to work, but I am pretty noob at JS. The problem is that the fade effect works nicely in chrome, but the picture just shifts without a fade in Firefox and IE.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<style>
.bg_img_slider{
     min-height:530px;
     background-image:url("a.jpg");
     background-repeat:no-repeat; 
     background-position:center;
     background-size:cover;}
</style>

<script>
var newBg = [
    'b.jpg',
    'c.jpg',
    'd.jpg'
    ];
    var i = 0;
var rotateBg = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
    if(i > 2)
        i=0;
    $('.bg_img_slider').css({backgroundImage : 'url(' + newBg[i] + ')'}).fadeIn('slow', 1);
}, 3000); 
</script>

<div class="bg_img_slider"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not `backgroundImage`... it's `background-image`.

Comment: I see no reason why it should be working on Chrome. Can you create a jsFiddle.net example, or a stack snippet?

Comment: if you are expecting fadeIn to fade in a background image into a div, you are expecting the wrong behavior. fadeIn makes the DOM element "bg_img_slider" fade in, it has nothing to do with CSS background image.

Comment: Dont know if this link works: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=HcF1cd4gBH)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the jquery method fadeIn() you can use CSS3 transitions.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dowomentfart/u9ru4gk7/2/)**

```
.bg_img_slider {
    min-height:530px;
    background-image:url("http://texy.dk/a.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-transition: background-image .6s ease-in;
    transition: background-image .6s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome play with the ease timing to get your desired effect @daremachine

Comment: okay, thanks. However this sollution does not seem to fade in Firefox and IE?

Comment: still seems to just jump between images, whereas chrome has a nice fade. i have IE 11 and FF 36.